# Return aggregated values

Tags: python, mongodb, flask, mongodb-query

It's the first time a write a non-trivial mongodb query, and I came up with one that does work, but is 123 lines long! Surely there must be a way to write it in a more concise way.

The purpose of the query is to return aggregated (average) values, using groups that are determined by the `$interval` parameter in seconds. Start and stop time are aligned to a multiple of the interval, so that the boundary values do not depend on the exact timestamp of the limit.

```py
data_points_aggr = {
    'datasource': {
        'source': 'data_points',
        'query_objectid_as_string': True,
        'aggregation': {
            'pipeline': [
                {
                    "$match": {
                        "$expr": {
                            "$and": [{
                                "$gte": [
                                    {
                                        "$toLong": "$time_stamp"
                                    },
                                    {
                                        "$subtract": [
                                            {
                                                "$toLong": "$start",
                                            },
                                            {
                                                "$mod": [
                                                    {
                                                        "$subtract": [
                                                            {
                                                                "$toLong":
                                                                "$start",
                                                            },
                                                            1,
                                                        ],
                                                    },
                                                    {
                                                        "$multiply":
                                                        [1000, "$interval"]
                                                    },
                                                ],
                                            },
                                        ],
                                    },
                                ]
                            }, {
                                "$lte": [
                                    {
                                        "$toLong": "$time_stamp"
                                    },
                                    {
                                        "$subtract": [
                                            {
                                                "$toLong": "$end",
                                            },
                                            {
                                                "$mod": [
                                                    {
                                                        "$add": [
                                                            {
                                                                "$toLong":
                                                                "$end",
                                                            },
                                                            0,
                                                        ],
                                                    },
                                                    {
                                                        "$multiply":
                                                        [1000, "$interval"]
                                                    },
                                                ],
                                            },
                                        ],
                                    },
                                ]
                            }],
                        },
                        "prosumer_id": {
                            "$in": "$prosumer"
                        }
                    },
                },
                {
                    "$group": {
                        "_id": {
                            "prosumer_id": "$prosumer_id",
                            "date": {
                                "$toDate": {
                                    "$add": [{
                                        "$subtract": [
                                            {
                                                "$toLong": "$time_stamp"
                                            },
                                            {
                                                "$mod": [
                                                    {
                                                        "$subtract": [{
                                                            "$toLong":
                                                            "$time_stamp"
                                                        }, 1]
                                                    },
                                                    {
                                                        "$multiply":
                                                        [1000, "$interval"]
                                                    },
                                                ],
                                            },
                                        ],
                                    }, {
                                        "$subtract": [{
                                            "$multiply": [1000, "$interval"]
                                        }, 1]
                                    }],
                                },
                            },
                        },
                        "consumption": {
                            "$avg": "$grid_consumption_w"
                        },
                    },
                },
                {
                    "$sort": {
                        "_id.date": 1
                    }
                },
            ]
        }
    },
}
```

Here is a sample of the data in the table:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5ee8e0f3aa9b673194b18a2c"), "time_stamp" : ISODate("2015-07-08T22:15:00Z"), "acpower_w" : 0, "grid_feed_in_w" : 0, "grid_consumption_w" : 0, "acpower2_w" : 0, "prosumer_id" : ObjectId("5ee8e0b100871cbb09d9fda0") }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5ee8e0f3aa9b673194b18a2d"), "time_stamp" : ISODate("2015-07-08T22:30:00Z"), "acpower_w" : 0, "grid_feed_in_w" : 0, "grid_consumption_w" : 0, "acpower2_w" : 0, "prosumer_id" : ObjectId("5ee8e0b100871cbb09d9fda0") }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5ee8e0f3aa9b673194b18a2e"), "time_stamp" : ISODate("2015-07-08T22:45:00Z"), "acpower_w" : 0, "grid_feed_in_w" : 0, "grid_consumption_w" : 0, "acpower2_w" : 0, "prosumer_id" : ObjectId("5ee8e0b100871cbb09d9fda0") }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5ee8e0f3aa9b673194b18a2f"), "time_stamp" : ISODate("2015-07-08T23:00:00Z"), "acpower_w" : 0, "grid_feed_in_w" : 0, "grid_consumption_w" : 0, "acpower2_w" : 0, "prosumer_id" : ObjectId("5ee8e0b100871cbb09d9fda0") }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5ee8e0f3aa9b673194b18a30"), "time_stamp" : ISODate("2015-07-08T23:15:00Z"), "acpower_w" : 0, "grid_feed_in_w" : 1, "grid_consumption_w" : 2, "acpower2_w" : 0, "prosumer_id" : ObjectId("5ee8e0b100871cbb09d9fda0") }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5ee8e0f3aa9b673194b18a31"), "time_stamp" : ISODate("2015-07-08T23:30:00Z"), "acpower_w" : 0, "grid_feed_in_w" : 1, "grid_consumption_w" : 0, "acpower2_w" : 0, "prosumer_id" : ObjectId("5ee8e0b100871cbb09d9fda0") }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5ee8e0f3aa9b673194b18a32"), "time_stamp" : ISODate("2015-07-08T23:45:00Z"), "acpower_w" : 0, "grid_feed_in_w" : 0, "grid_consumption_w" : 0, "acpower2_w" : 0, "prosumer_id" : ObjectId("5ee8e0b100871cbb09d9fda0") }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5ee8e0f3aa9b673194b18a33"), "time_stamp" : ISODate("2015-07-09T00:00:00Z"), "acpower_w" : 0, "grid_feed_in_w" : 0, "grid_consumption_w" : 0, "acpower2_w" : 0, "prosumer_id" : ObjectId("5ee8e0b100871cbb09d9fda0") }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5ee8e0f3aa9b673194b18a34"), "time_stamp" : ISODate("2015-07-09T00:15:00Z"), "acpower_w" : 0, "grid_feed_in_w" : 0, "grid_consumption_w" : 0, "acpower2_w" : 0, "prosumer_id" : ObjectId("5ee8e0b100871cbb09d9fda0") }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5ee8e0f3aa9b673194b18a35"), "time_stamp" : ISODate("2015-07-09T00:30:00Z"), "acpower_w" : 0, "grid_feed_in_w" : 0, "grid_consumption_w" : 0, "acpower2_w" : 0, "prosumer_id" : ObjectId("5ee8e0b100871cbb09d9fda0") }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5ee8e0f3aa9b673194b18a36"), "time_stamp" : ISODate("2015-07-09T00:45:00Z"), "acpower_w" : 0, "grid_feed_in_w" : 0, "grid_consumption_w" : 0, "acpower2_w" : 0, "prosumer_id" : ObjectId("5ee8e0b100871cbb09d9fda0") }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5ee8e0f3aa9b673194b18a37"), "time_stamp" : ISODate("2015-07-09T01:00:00Z"), "acpower_w" : 0, "grid_feed_in_w" : 0, "grid_consumption_w" : 0, "acpower2_w" : 0, "prosumer_id" : ObjectId("5ee8e0b100871cbb09d9fda0") }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5ee8e0f3aa9b673194b18a38"), "time_stamp" : ISODate("2015-07-09T01:15:00Z"), "acpower_w" : 0, "grid_feed_in_w" : 2, "grid_consumption_w" : 2, "acpower2_w" : 0, "prosumer_id" : ObjectId("5ee8e0b100871cbb09d9fda0") }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5ee8e0f3aa9b673194b18a39"), "time_stamp" : ISODate("2015-07-09T01:30:00Z"), "acpower_w" : 0, "grid_feed_in_w" : 0, "grid_consumption_w" : 0, "acpower2_w" : 0, "prosumer_id" : ObjectId("5ee8e0b100871cbb09d9fda0") }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5ee8e0f3aa9b673194b18a3a"), "time_stamp" : ISODate("2015-07-09T01:45:00Z"), "acpower_w" : 0, "grid_feed_in_w" : 1, "grid_consumption_w" : 0, "acpower2_w" : 0, "prosumer_id" : ObjectId("5ee8e0b100871cbb09d9fda0") }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5ee8e0f3aa9b673194b18a3b"), "time_stamp" : ISODate("2015-07-09T02:00:00Z"), "acpower_w" : 0, "grid_feed_in_w" : 0, "grid_consumption_w" : 0, "acpower2_w" : 0, "prosumer_id" : ObjectId("5ee8e0b100871cbb09d9fda0") }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5ee8e0f3aa9b673194b18a3c"), "time_stamp" : ISODate("2015-07-09T02:15:00Z"), "acpower_w" : 0, "grid_feed_in_w" : 0, "grid_consumption_w" : 0, "acpower2_w" : 0, "prosumer_id" : ObjectId("5ee8e0b100871cbb09d9fda0") }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5ee8e0f3aa9b673194b18a3d"), "time_stamp" : ISODate("2015-07-09T02:30:00Z"), "acpower_w" : 0, "grid_feed_in_w" : 0, "grid_consumption_w" : 0, "acpower2_w" : 0, "prosumer_id" : ObjectId("5ee8e0b100871cbb09d9fda0") }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5ee8e0f3aa9b673194b18a3e"), "time_stamp" : ISODate("2015-07-09T02:45:00Z"), "acpower_w" : 0, "grid_feed_in_w" : 0, "grid_consumption_w" : 0, "acpower2_w" : 0, "prosumer_id" : ObjectId("5ee8e0b100871cbb09d9fda0") }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5ee8e0f3aa9b673194b18a3f"), "time_stamp" : ISODate("2015-07-09T03:00:00Z"), "acpower_w" : 0, "grid_feed_in_w" : 2, "grid_consumption_w" : 2, "acpower2_w" : 0, "prosumer_id" : ObjectId("5ee8e0b100871cbb09d9fda0") }
```

Here is a request:

```bsh
curl --location --request GET 'https://db.flexgrid-project.eu/data_points_aggr?aggregate={%22$start%22:%20%222017-07-11T19:05:00%22,%22$end%22:%222017-07-11T22:00:01%22,%20%22$prosumer%22:%20[%225ee8e1fc00871cbb09d9fdf8%22,%20%225ee8e0fa00871cbb09d9fdc0%22],%20%22$interval%22:%203600}' \
--header 'Authorization: Bearer lep0E....'
```

And here is the output:

```
{
    "_items": [
        {
            "_id": {
                "prosumer_id": "5ee8e1fc00871cbb09d9fdf8",
                "date": "2017-07-11T20:00:00"
            },
            "consumption": 3.25
        },
        {
            "_id": {
                "prosumer_id": "5ee8e0fa00871cbb09d9fdc0",
                "date": "2017-07-11T20:00:00"
            },
            "consumption": 7.25
        },
        {
            "_id": {
                "prosumer_id": "5ee8e0fa00871cbb09d9fdc0",
                "date": "2017-07-11T21:00:00"
            },
            "consumption": 7.75
        },
        {
            "_id": {
                "prosumer_id": "5ee8e1fc00871cbb09d9fdf8",
                "date": "2017-07-11T21:00:00"
            },
            "consumption": 2.75
        },
        {
            "_id": {
                "prosumer_id": "5ee8e0fa00871cbb09d9fdc0",
                "date": "2017-07-11T22:00:00"
            },
            "consumption": 7.75
        },
        {
            "_id": {
                "prosumer_id": "5ee8e1fc00871cbb09d9fdf8",
                "date": "2017-07-11T22:00:00"
            },
            "consumption": 2.25
        }
    ],
    "_meta": {
        "page": 1,
        "max_results": 25,
        "total": 6
    },
    "_links": {
        "parent": {
            "title": "home",
            "href": "/"
        },
        "self": {
            "title": "data_points_aggr",
            "href": "data_points_aggr?aggregate={\"$start\": \"2017-07-11T19:05:00\",\"$end\":\"2017-07-11T22:00:01\", \"$prosumer\": [\"5ee8e1fc00871cbb09d9fdf8\", \"5ee8e0fa00871cbb09d9fdc0\"], \"$interval\": 3600}"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Perhaps this use case fits https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/server-side-javascript/ and https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/store-javascript-function-on-server/

Comment: @DimaTisnek: Thanks, this looks like a good approach for reducing the line count, since JS code will be much shorter. My only concern is the big warning on the top of the page that says `Do not store application logic in the database. There are performance limitations to running JavaScript inside of MongoDB. Application code also is typically most effective when it shares version control with the application itself.`, so there seems to be a tradeoff between code clarity and efficiency.